# Is the light/fan combo in my shower safe?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, light

In all of the bathrooms, there is a recessed light/exhaust fan combo installed. I assume, due to the combo feature, is the reason there is no cover over the light fixture.  However, the same light/exhaust is also located inside the master shower - not in the damp area but, the actual wet area.  Visualize yourself taking a shower and looking directly above you as your washing your hair, with water spraying and splashing everywhere, you look right up into the can of the light!  So, out of precaution, we keep the switch off -ALL THE TIME! Is this safe and to code?

Comment: Can you get us a photo of the fixture nameplate?

Comment: i don't see a _major problem_ if you can't accidentally reach the fixture. even if water got in there, all it would do is drip back down on you, it can't bring the electricity with it, unless you have a literal stream coming down.  is it the best design? no. Is it legal? i can't say. Will it kill you in the shower? no way.

Comment: We'll need a photo of the fixture nameplate to look up its listing and see if the thing's OK for the application...

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I have never liked lights (or fans) in the shower, because they are a maintenance nightmare. That being said I know of no restriction about putting one in a shower area unless you are able to touch it or it comes into contact with the spray of the shower. So I am assuming your fixture/fan is high enough to meet all jurisdictional codes.

My only question would be if this was installed during construction or was an add in by a previous owner. If it's the latter, you may want to check with local code enforcement to see if it should be removed. I like your idea of never using it.

Stay safe.